# How to not let sum of child field not exceed parent field in MS Access

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, constraints

I have MS Access database file with following tables

Table `In`

```
Id | Quantity
------------------------
1  | 8
```

Table `Out`

```
Id | Parent    | Quantity
-------------------------
1  | 1         | 2
2  | 1         | 5
```

Table `In` is a parent table and Table `Out` is related table.

**I need following constraint to be enforced** (pseudo formula):

```
In.Quantity >= Sum(Out.Quantity)
```

That is: Sum of outgoing quantities cannot be greater than incoming quantity

*I am developing a Winforms application. The user will make changes (Insert, Update and delete) to both `In` and `Out`*

Comment: Rethink your db model. Usually you have one table with stock movements (out is negative). Then check at where the user edits, inserts data that inputs are valid. If you would use a database with triggers (like SQL-Server; ...), that could be made at database level.

Comment: Note that Access supports triggers (in the form of data macros) and cross-table check constraints just fine. While there are tasks that require SQL server's better trigger capability, validating input by comparing to a different table isn't one of them. It looks, though, like the OP wants a C# solution

Comment: @Erik A, I want a solution at database level for Winform (C#) application

Comment: @ErikA Can we rely on data-macro triggers? I don't rely on any access backend! That's why I always suggest using a different database. Input should be validated to same table(in/out in one table) or don't you agree on that?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I certainly agree that SQL server as a back end is more reliable than Access as a back end. There are situations one chooses Access anyway, mainly for cost/ease of use. I prefer to rely on constraints over data macros for validation. In/out in one table depends on the exact situation but is generally preferable. However, if you have a clear 1-many relationship with in-out, it might make sense to store them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CHECK` constraint to validate the condition.

```sql
ALTER TABLE Out 
ADD CONSTRAINT NoNegativeTotal
CHECK(
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM In
        INNER JOIN Out ON In.Id = Out.Id
        GROUP BY In.Id, In.Quantity
        HAVING SUM(Out.Quantity) > In.Quantity
    )
)
```

You might want to add the same constraint to the `In`  table, since if someone changes the `In.Quantity` field to violate the constraint, that'll lock down all editing in the `Out` table except edits that make the constraint valid again.

Check constraints need to be executed either in ANSI 92 compatible mode, or using ADO (e.g. using `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`). More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27982995/7296893).

Answer (score 0):

Use the *BeforeUpdate* event of the subform to compare the sum of field *Quantity* with `Me.Parent!Quantity.Value`.

If exceeding, set `Cancel = True` and pop a message.